# InfluxDB Cannot see databases from localhost:8083 + Cannot access Command Line Interface

Tags: clojure, access-rights, influxdb

Please feel free to redirect me to any other place if this isn't the right one for this question.

Problem: When I log to the administration panel : "localhost:8083" with "root" "root" I cannot see the existing databases nor the data in it. Also, I have no way to access InfluxDB from the command line.

Also the line `sudo /etc/init.d/influxdb start` does not work for my setup. I have to go into /etc/init.d/ and run `sudo ./influxdb start -config=config.toml` in order to get the server running.

I've installed influxDB v0.8 from https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.8/introduction/installation.html for Ubuntu 14.04.

I've been developing a Clojure program using the Capacitor API just to get started and interact with InfluxDB. It runs well, I can create delete, insert and query a database without problems.

`netstat -anp | grep LISTEN` confirms me that ports 8083 8086 8090 and 8099 are listening.

I've been Googling all around but cannot manage to get a solution.

Thanks for the support and enjoy building things !

Comment: Try upgrading to influx 0.9.1 which is most recent version and hopefully more stable. By default when you connect there's no database present, you have to create one first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: the database weren't visible in firefox but everything is visible in Chromium!

Why couldn't I access the CLI ? I was expecting the v0.8 to behave exactly like the v0.9.

You help was appreciated anyway !

Comment: The CLI only works with 0.9+. The 0.8 versions of InfluxDB have no support for the CLI.

Please see https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/concepts/08_vs_09.html for the many changes between 0.8 and 0.9. They are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

For InfluxDB 0.9 the CLI could be started with:

```
/opt/influxdb/influx
```

then you can display available databases:

```
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 0.9.1
InfluxDB shell 0.9.1
> show databases
name: databases
---------------
name
collectd
graphite

> use collectd
Using database collectd

> show series limit 5
```

You can try creating new database from CLI:

```
> CREATE DATABASE mydb
```

or with curl command:

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"
```

Web UI should be available on http://localhost:8083